getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All My Notes"); This line cause to crash my Android application lunch
I am working on Android Application. In that application I face an issue. The problem is in the first line of this code. Launching the application doesn't work.
This is the code part of it:
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All My Notes");
    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar!=null){
        actionBar.setTitle("My Notes");
    }

    mcreatenotesfab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(notesactivity.this, createnote.class));

        }
    });

This is the Logcat of the error:
2024-07-03 13:52:33.787  6285-6285  AndroidRuntime          com.example.mynotesapp               E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.mynotesapp, PID: 6285
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mynotesapp/com.example.mynotesapp.notesactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at com.example.mynotesapp.notesactivity.onCreate(notesactivity.java:69)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (6285) for package com.example.mynotesapp ----------------------------

I tried commenting the first line of the provided code. The application launched successfully but it does show the Action Bar of my application. I am expecting to implement the Action Bar of my application
//getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All My Notes");
    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar!=null){
        actionBar.setTitle("My Notes");
    }

    mcreatenotesfab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(notesactivity.this, createnote.class));

        }
    });


Can you post which theme your activity and the app are using?

this code i wrote in NotesAcitivity and My application About Note Pad
